# How do we use the inference toolkit to create a container that will be provided inference scripts by users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I would like to create a pre-built container that will be shared within SageMaker. Users will pass an inference script to the container using the `model_fn`, `predict_fn` pattern. This is the same pattern used by pre-built containers like [XGBoost](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container).

But when AWS developed the XGBoost container they used the now deprecated [sagemaker-containers](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers) package, as shown [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-xgboost-container/blob/master/src/sagemaker_xgboost_container/serving.py#L150-L153). How am I supposed to the same pattern using the toolkit? I have tried creating a default handler service, but I need my user to create the non-default versions.

In the docs, everything implies that I should create a container with this built-in but that will prevent my users from overriding.